# Restrict number of concurrent reducers per user

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way to restrict the number of concurrent reduce slots per user in hadoop? We want to ensure no single user is using up all available reduce slots at any time.

Comment: We are using version 0.20.203.1.

Comment: Just curious - why only reduce slots and not map slots?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the [FairScheduler in the current version of Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/fair_scheduler.html).  You could allocate one pool per user and then set `maxReduces`.  However, this option is not available in the [FairScheduler with 0.20.203](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.203.0/fair_scheduler.html).  This version conveniently has `minReduces` without `maxReduces`.